# Can we update the existing facebookAppId?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, facebook, app-id

I've started working on a new react-native project, this app has a facebookAppId that was created by a developer that has left the company many years ago and didn't leave details of the facebook account. Now we can't implement any facebook related changes because we don't have access to that account. Is it possible to create a new app id in the facebook dashboard and update the existing facebookAppId in the project? What are the cons? The app is on apple store and playstore, will this change affect the existing app? Any advise and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One major con would be, that since user ids are app-scoped these days, you would get _different_ IDs for all your already existing users, the next time they log in.